# Microsoft Modern Keyboard on Linux Compatibility

Tags: drivers, keyboard, bluetooth

I am planning to buy the Microsoft Modern Keyboard with Fingerprint scanner but I am wondering if any of you guys have managed to make it work over Bluetooth and if the fingerprint scanner is working for log in. I really like the keyboard but unfortunately, there isn't information on the net if it is really working or not. I was only able to find this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966097/microsoft-modern-keyboard-with-ubuntu) so far and it doesn't say whether the suggested method is really working or not. I haven't found any information about the compatibility of the fingerprint scanner with Linux either.

Comment: Linux  or Ubuntu?

Comment: I am running Manjaro, but I guess if it works on Ubuntu, it will work under Manjaro as well.